# Many To Many Relationships Entity Framework with duplicate child items

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

have a question about using entity framework and setting up the relationships between entities.
What I want to achieve is to have duplicate items in a collection which are from a separate entity.

```
List<MenuItem> menuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
MenuItem m1 = menuRepository.GetItemByCode("001");
MenuItem m2 = menuRepository.GetItemByCode("001"); //same item but want to store it additionally as m2.MenuItemExtras will be different from m1.MenuItemExtras

menuItems.Add(m1);
menuItems.Add(m2);

Order order = new Order();
order.MenuItems = menuItems;
orderRepository.Save(order);
```

This works fine but I only get one record inserted into the table
i.e.

```
OrderMenuItem
    OrderPK = 1, MenuItemPK = 1 //Id of menuItem with code "001"
```

what I would probably want is something like:
OrderMenuItem table to contain a third column with it's own primary key, rather than it being a composite of OrderPK and MenuItemPK. i.e.

```
OrderMenuItem 
    OrderMenuItemId = 1, OrderPK = 1, MenuItemPK = 1
    OrderMenuItemId = 2, OrderPK = 1, MenuItemPK = 1
```

Not sure of how to actually achieve this and whether or not I need to redefine my class relationships. Thanks for any opinions.

Below is the classes and snippets of the DbContext:

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }

    public Order()
    {
        MenuItems = new Collection<MenuItem>();
    }
}

public class MenuItem
{
    public Guid MenuItemId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MenuItemExtras> MenuItemExtras { get; set; }
}

public class MenuItemCategory
{
    public Guid MenuItemCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string HotKey { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
}

public class MenuItemExtras
{
    public Guid MenuItemExtrasId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

In my DbContext on my OnModelCreating ovveride I have the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MenuItemCategory>().Property(m => m.MenuItemCategoryId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
modelBuilder.Entity<MenuItemCategory>().HasMany(m => m.MenuItems).WithMany();

modelBuilder.Entity<MenuItem>().Property(m => m.MenuItemId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
modelBuilder.Entity<MenuItem>().HasMany(m => m.MenuItemExtras).WithMany();

modelBuilder.Entity<MenuItemExtras>().Property(m => m.MenuItemExtrasId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().Property(o => o.OrderId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasMany(m => m.MenuItems).WithMany();
```

Which generates the following tables:

```
MenuItem
MenuItemCategory
MenuItemCategoryMenuItem
MenuItemExtras
MenuItemMenuItemExtras
Order
OrderMenuItems
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are talking about Pizza & Co. here, not about drop down menus, right?

In my understanding you must distinguish between the *possible* Extras a `MenuItem` can have and the actual *ordered* Extras a guest wants to have together with the ordered `MenuItem`.

The `MenuItem` class can stay unchanged and it describes all *possible* Extras a restaurant offers for a particular `MenuItem`:

```
public class MenuItem // Pizza Margherita
{
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<MenuItemExtras> MenuItemExtras { get; set; }
    // Possible Extras: Paprika or Ham or Mushrooms
}
```

But to model the *ordered* Extras (which I would expect to be a subset of the *possible* Extras) you must introduce a new class `OrderMenuItem`. An `Order` has a collection of `Items` of this new type `OrderMenuItem` (not directly of `MenuItem`):

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderMenuItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

The `OrderMenuItem` has a reference to the `MenuItem` the guest has ordered and a collection of `MenuItemExtras` the guest has selected from all possible Extras:

```
public class OrderMenuItem
{
    public int OrderMenuItemId { get; set; }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }

    public int MenuItemId { get; set; }
    public MenuItem MenuItem { get; set; } // Pizza Margherita

    public ICollection<MenuItemExtras> MenuItemExtras { get; set; }
    // Ordered Extras: Paprika and Mushrooms (subset of Possible Extras)
}
```

The new relationships can be defined like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OrderMenuItem>()
    .HasRequired(o => o.Order)
    .WithMany(o => o.Items)
    .HasForeignKey(o => o.OrderId);

modelBuilder.Entity<OrderMenuItem>()
    .HasRequired(o => o.MenuItem)
    .WithMany() // a MenuItem can be ordered in many orders
    .HasForeignKey(o => o.MenuItemId);

modelBuilder.Entity<OrderMenuItem>()
    .HasMany(o => o.MenuItemExtras)
    .WithMany() // an Extra can be ordered in many orders
    .Map(m => {
        m.ToTable("OrderMenuItemMenuItemExtras");
        m.MapLeftKey("OrderMenuItemId");
        m.MapRightKey("MenuItemExtraId");
    });
```

The `OrderMenuItem` table will have its own primary key `OrderMenuItemId` and two foreign keys, one key to `Order` and one key to `MenuItem` - as you expect it. The relationship to the ordered Extras is a new many-to-many relationship with a join table named `OrderMenuItemMenuItemExtras`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes this is correct and I realized after I posted the questions that the perfect example to look at was the Northwind database which does have the equivalent and introduce a third table called orderdetails which is the collection of products which is what you have suggested. Thanks again.